# how to get "Newest Record" when fetching record With Magical Record

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

How do I get the latest record when fetching  records?

for example:

- first iteration i save  "Singapore" with object name  Country,
- second iteration i save  "USA" with object name  Country,second

Now when i fetch it

```
SomeDatabase *Country = [SomeDatabase MR_findFirst];

NSLog(@"Country Name---->%@",Country.Name);
```

I get "Singapore",

I want get the last record inserted to coredata, which is supposed to be "USA".

Comment: ASAIK, Core Data doesn't maintain an order of which object was added last. So I guess you're out of luck here, unless your store the creation date in a dedicated field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straight forward way is to add a "createdDate" or similar date field to your entity. Then you can simply use the query:

```
[MyEntity MR_findFirstOrderedByAttribute:@"createdDate" ascending:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 3**
If you want to add extra query arguments:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(attribute1 = %@ && attribute2 = %@ && date <= %@)", argument1, argument2, yourdate as NSDate)
let fetch = YourCCEntity.mr_requestAllSorted(by: "date", ascending: false, with: predicate)
let latestObject = YourCCEntity.mr_executeFetchRequestAndReturnFirstObject(fetch)
```

The `as NSDate` is necessary because of an Xcode bug (Some Swift classes don't work with NSPredicate arguments)